# Amateur student making a demo of electromagnetic induction via copper coil and magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, light-emitting-diodes

I'm trying to observe electromagnetic induction by creating a copper coil solded to a diode led and waving an alnico magnet inside the copper coil's core.

You can see my amateur setting below (remember, I'm doing this first time in my life and I know it might look ridiculous, but I do this for study purposes ;))

I have checked that all the wires in the system form a closet circuit with a multimeter, but when I tried waving the magnet around the core I noticed no spark in the led, even at total darkness.

What do you think is the most probable cause that I noticed no spark in the led? I have three suspicions:

> 1) The resistance in the diode led is too high for this setting to produce enough current.
>
> 2) I don't have enough loops in the copper coil.
>
> 3) I require a stronger magnet, such as neodym magnet.

[image]

**My question is:** What do you think my problem in this setting is? What do I need to change in my system to make this work?

UPDATE:

I did additional test on the diode led itself. I noticed that I could not get the led on with a single 1,5V battery, but I could get it to light up with two 1,5V batteries:

[image]
 so I guess I need a more powerful magnetic field inside the coil.

Comment: What wire did you use and how many turns are there?

Comment: Hi Alex, it's copper wire and the length of the wire is maybe 25-30 meters long. With a 3 cm diameter of the coil there should be around 265- 318 loops/turns.The copper wire is around 1mm thick.

Comment: Is the wire insulated?

Comment: Hi Alex, no it is not. Actually, now when you mentioned the number of turns, I read from somewhere that there should be around 1000-2000 turns..?

Comment: The wire must be insulated. The picture is not visible, but it is possible that the wire is coated with insulation.

Comment: Hi Alex, okay thank you. I will try burning the insulation out with a lighter.

Comment: Update: I burned the connection points of the led and copper wire, re-solded them together, checked for current with a multimeter. There is a beep sound signaling for current in the all parts of the system, except between two ends of of the led diode. Maybe the diode has too high resistance?...it should be functional and brand new.

Comment: It might be strength of magnet.  [Look at this video.](https://youtu.be/gZpa7FYR_pw)

Comment: Thank you @Farcher

Comment: This won't work if the wire isn't insulated; you should check that with the multimeter. Are you putting the magnet *inside* the coil, or are you waving it around the outside of the coil? You'll need to generate more than the forward voltage of the LED (a little over 2V) to light it up.

Comment: @PM2Ring but of course, excellent. Thank you very much. I will get an insulated wire and try again and yes, I'm waving the magnet inside the coil. I will report the results here when I succeed.

Comment: You could try hooking up the multimeter in place of the LED to see how much voltage you are generating.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in lighting the LED up, thank you for your help!. As suggested, I used thin insulated copper wire and two powerful rod-shaped neodymium magnets.

I will post later the details of the experiment.